# Download Microsoft MediaRoom ADK (SDK)

Tags: adk

I am new to Microsoft MediaRoom. I want to download Microsoft MediaRoom ADK(SDK). I tried a lot but did not found any link for download. So please can any one give me a link for this.

MediaRoom is used for develop application for set-top-box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the MicrosoftMediaroomADK.msi linked off of my Drop Box. Let me know if you can get to it.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61494529/ADK/MicrosoftMediaroomADK.msi

It's MR20 I think.

Comment: I doubt you are allowed to distribute this stuff openly like this

Comment: What skills are required in order to start developing with Microsoft Mediaroom library and what type of applications can be developed using it?

Comment: .NET languages, generally C#. Also XML and XAML application, so web technologies. You can write IPTV based applications. I've seen notification apps, alert apps, weather apps, music apps, the possibilities are limitless.

Comment: Can you please tell us from where we can download MicrosoftMediaroomADK because the link you have posted is broken.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will find all necessary files under http://mediaroomsds.microsoft.com. You need a working Microsoft account however.

Comment: Well sir, you need MicrosoftMediaroomADK.msi